# Granger-Causality test result interpretation

Tags: time-series, interpretation, model-selection, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have fitted a VAR model to first-differenced financial data, and conducted a Granger-Causality test on stationary data. The results can be seen below:

[image]

The above results show that only one variable seems to Granger-Cause the price return of gold, highlighted in green. However, there are many other variables that are quite close to rejecting the Null-hypothesis. In these cases, could one say that the other variables partially Granger-Cause the forecasting variable, and therefore include them in a multi-variate model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Either a variable Granger-causes another one or it does not. There can be no partial causation. Think of it in terms of model equations; either a coefficient is zero or it is not, there is no other possibility. What can be partial is your certainty. You can be somewhat certain that a variable Granger-causes another one.
2. You want to use results of a Granger-causality test for feature selection when building a forecasting model. That boils down to using statistically significant lags of some variables. Rob Hyndman has explained in ["Statistical tests for variable selection"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/) why that is a bad idea. Instead, consider selecting your variables using information criteria such as AIC that are optimized for feature selection for forecasting.
3. Using a VAR for forecasting stock prices or gold price sounds quite naive, unless it is meant as an exercise. If these prices were following VAR type of patterns, investors would be tempted to exploit them. By doing so (buying low and selling high), they would affect the supply and demand of these assets, so that the price patterns would disappear. As there are a lot of people and firms trying to do that all over the world, this happens very fast. Therefore, patterns disappear very fast – most of the time before you are able to exploit them.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd point.

Comment: @User1865345, thank you. The first two points are the important ones from the statistical perspective, but I thought I would add the last one just in case.

Comment: Of course, Richard. The whole answer is good but the third point is especially critical to the new learners who take VAR or its cousins as panacea and this probably stems out from outright jumping from initial studies to applications.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clarifying answer!

Comment: @bullfighter, you are welcome!